# Outputting data with an Access Database but users stored in an SQL database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, database

I'm creating an ecommerce site using asp.net and a Access Datasource, I have used the pre-defined logging in and registering controls provided by Visual Studio 2010 which stores the user data in a SQL server.

For my site the content of the shopping cart is uploaded to a table in the access database, I need to however save the contents of the cart to a specific user ID.  For example if User number 1 orders book id's 4,7,2 this needs to be saved, but if user number 2 comes along and orders 4,1,7 this needs to be saved for them as well.

So a user can have many carts, this is sorted in access but with the user ID being saved to a different database is there anyway I can link the two databases so I can say

"Save bookid's 1,2,3 in tblcart where userID is the same as the logged in user"

Hope you understand what I mean.

Thanks

Comment: Is there any reason you don't just implement the Entire site in SQL server?

Answer (score 0):

From the sounds of it.  You don't need to do anything special.  So long as there is a user_id field stored in tblCart you should be fine.

You won't have any "official" relationships defined, but that doesn't really matter... if a logged in user wants to see all of their "carts" you would just do: SELECT * FROM tblCarts WHERE user_id = LoggedInUsersID.

Comment: Same as with if you, as an admin, needed to see multiple user's carts... do one query to get all of the users out of the login DB, and then a second query using the user_id data on the carts DB.

Comment: The main issue in my mind was to do with the fact that the users ID was a range of characters while the access users ID was just an auto increment 1 then 2 etc.

Would this still work? Or would something else have to be done?

Comment: @user527330 yes this will be a problem because you will want the two userid fields to match. You should change the field in the cart database to match the field from the membership database. Rather than having it be an auto increment, change it to a character field and just enter the userid as part of your insert statement. I don't have access on this machine so I am not sure what the correct field would be.